# Using Sidekiq with Nokogiri for scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, delayed-job, sidekiq

I'm using Rails with Nokogiri. I have some heavy scraping tasks that I would like to execute in the background with Sidekiq.

The problem is, I followed the three steps mentioned on sidekiq.org but nothing happened. What am I missing?

What follows is one of my scrapes without using Sidekiq, which works fine, but the main problem is, a couple of scrapes like this makes the page loads very slowly.

```
#my controller
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com"))
@head = {}
doc.xpath('//div[5]/h3/a').each do |link|
@head[link.text.strip] = link['href']
end

#my view
<% if @head %>
<% @head.each do |key, value| %>
<a href="<%= "#{value}" %>" target='_blank'><%= "#{key}" %></a><% end %>
<% end %>
```

What follows is my attempt to use Sidekiq:

```
#my controller
class HomeController < ApplicationController
HardWorker.index_async('index', 1)
end

#my hard_worker
class HardWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker
def index
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com"))
@head = {}
doc.xpath('//div[5]/h3/a').each do |link|
@head[link.text.strip] = link['href']
end
end

#my view
the same
```

Comment: We don't know what HTML you're parsing, nor do we know what site you're retrieving it from, and without that sort of information we have no idea what could be slowing your processing. Big, convoluted HTML documents could take a second if there are lots of anchors in the `h3` tags. Also, if you are hitting a number of pages on one site and not being a good net-citizen and slowly requesting pages, but instead are sacking and pillaging, then they could be throttling your requests to avoid saturating their hosts and network. As is we can't help you. Explain the problem better.

Comment: Are you preprocessing the information or trying to do it on demand? If on demand, then consider the experience of someone wanting to use your page who has to wait as you request another page and scrape it. Would you wait the 3-4 seconds with no response? Don't expect users to wait. Do it in the background before the request is made by a user and then serve it from a cache.

Comment: - What slow my processing is the fact that I am scrpaing dozens of site
- The scraped sites are online newspapwer. Scraping only one page/site, and some headlines by page (which means some headlines/site)
- I asked the permission for every administrator, they were ok and the only condition is that I advertize about their sites. Fair enough.
- My wish is to preprocessing, and you are absolutely right and it’s wholly my point: it’s out of competition to load a page during 10-20 seconds. That’s why I would like to execute this scraping on background with Sidekiq (and I am only a beginner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a *nix host, I'd recommend running a separate, non-Rails Ruby script that is allowed to talk to the database and update a summary table containing the information you need to return to clients. There is no reason to have it run inside Rails or even to load the Rails stack.

You can use [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) to run Ruby code:

> `runner` runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively.

The code will have access to Active Record and will be able to use all the same Rails-like configuration and methods, it just won't load the web-side of the stack, making it much lighter-weight and faster to load.

Use cron to periodically fire off that separate Ruby script, loop through a table, or YAML file, containing the URLs to process and then insert the results.